# Can I resolve a MX record using hosts file?

Tags: dns, hosts

To test mail server I need an `MX` record in DNS server, it always with a delay because DNS cache, I need to make it faster. Is there a way make an `MX` record locally like `A` record by `etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I think you can only map hosts to ip addresses not mx records in a hosts file but maybe someone has a creative solution for you. BTW, have you tried temporarily reducing the TTL for MX record changes? I say, temp, as you don't want it low ongoing as that will result in a lot of unnecessary DNS overhead and possible slowness but when you make DNS changes it's reasonable to set it low for a bit.

Comment: And be sure to clear your local DNS cache. For example, on OSX High Sierra:   
```$ sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; sleep 2; echo macOS DNS Cache Reset | say```

Comment: 2 points: your DNS recursive resolver will cache MX records as it does other records. You are probably over engineering  something that is not needed. And if your DNS server is too slow to your taste you could install one locally on your machine. Second point: MTA/MUA query for MX first on the domain part and if no answers fallback to A/AAAA. So, depending on which email you are interested in there may not be any MX record in  fact.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, this works.

```
echo "10.10.10.1 mail.example.com" | sudo tee --append /etc/hosts > /dev/null

echo "disable_dns_lookups = yes" | sudo tee --append /etc/postfix/main.cf > /dev/null

systemctl restart postfix
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm managing to use postfix on a proxmox server to delivery the mail to a local mail server on a vm , with a different ip address from the dns mx record, i've found very useful this article, 
http://www.readonlymaio.org/rom/2018/01/16/force-postfix-to-search-mx-records-in-etc-hosts-file/

he leds me to disable the dns lookup in postfix to force it to use the hosts A record !!

it works

in the hosts 
X.X.X.X    example.com

Edit the /etc/postfix/main.cf file and add this line:

disable_dns_lookups = yes

after, restart postfix

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the link into your answer. The link could be outdated in the future.

Comment: 404 already, sadly